# Why can't add same row after deleting from dojo grid

Tags: dojo, grid

I am displaying some content using dojo EnhancedGrid. The users can add and delete the content to/from the grid. Adding and deleting from the store/grid work fine as long as the I use unique id (Id here is just a count/number starting from 1) for every row/item that is added to grid.

However, I would like to reuse the id if row/item with that id has been deleted from the grid but seems dojo grid doesn't allow that.

I am using grid.store.deleteItem(item) and grid.store.newItem(item) for delete/add. I 
am even calling grid._refresh() after deleteItem() but that is not making any difference.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using dojox.grid.cells.RowIndex(). This automatically creates a new cell/column in the grid called 'Row' which contains the unique integer value staring with 1. When you delete one or more rows from the grid, the row number for existing rows in the grid gets adjusted to reflect this change (always keeping row number in increment of 1) and therefore any new row that is added to the grid gets next row number.

```
    var layout = [[
      new dojox.grid.cells.RowIndex({ width: '25px' }),
      {'name': 'Type', 'field': 'type', 'width': '50px'},
      {'name': 'Description', 'field': 'desc', 'width': '200px', editable: true},
      {'name': 'Score', 'field': 'score', 'width': '37px'}
    ]];
```